# Adding a node in the beginning of XML parent node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlnode

I wanted to add a xmlNode in a parent but at the top/beginning. Is there a variant of `XMLNode.AppendChild()` that i can use?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking, or what you've tried. It would really help if you could provide a small example of what you're trying to do, and show code that attempts to achieve it, along with what happens compared with what you want to happen. I'd also strongly recommend using LINQ to XML if you possibly can, as a much better XML API than the `XmlDocument` one.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understand your question you are probably looking for the `XmlNode.PrependChild()` method.
Example:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

//Create a new node.
XmlElement node = doc.CreateElement("price");

//Add the node to the document.
root.PrependChild(node);
```

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.prependchild%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is asking how to add a node to the beginning of the XML file. I did that in the following manner:

```
// This is the main xml document
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

// This part is creation of RootNode, however you want
XmlNode RootNode = document.CreateElement("Comments");
document.AppendChild(RootNode);

//Adding first child node as usual
XmlNode CommentNode1 = document.CreateElement("UserComment");
RootNode.AppendChild(commentNode1);

//Now create a child node and add it to the beginning of the XML file
XmlNode CommentNode2 = document.CreateElement("UserComment");
RootNode.InsertBefore(commentNode2, RootNode.FirstChild);
```